# how iterate through lists inside of a list?

Tags: list, loops

I want to iterate through the list and through every list inside of it and subtract the the first item from the second item and at the end I want to add the returned sum together, heres what i have:

```
        def number(bus_stops):
            for i in range(len(bus_stops)):
              return sum(bus_stops[i][0] - bus_stops[i][1])
        print(number([[10,0], [4,5], [3,2]]))
```

this looks pretty sense to me but it doesn't work any help would be appreciated (also if you can't tell I'm a beginner)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this example how to iterate the list, unpack it and compute the total sum:

```py
def number(bus_stops):
    total = 0
    for a, b in bus_stops:
        total += b - a  # <-- subtract first item from second, add to total
    return total


print(number([[10, 0], [4, 5], [3, 2]]))
```

Prints:

```
-10
```

---

Or using `sum()`:

```py
def number(bus_stops):
    return sum(b - a for a, b in bus_stops)
```

Comment: thanks but can you tell me what was wrong with my code

Comment: @hobbyiscoding Maybe swap `b` and `a`? In your question you ask how to substract first item from the second, but your code is subtracting second from first.